# Ensuring Async Action Has Completed in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, firebase

I need to run concurrent queries to Firebase in swift. How can I ensure that a looped query has finished before another action is allowed to start in my app?

For example, the first query is a straightforward, and simply pulls data. but the second, iterates through an array looking for a certain node in my firebase database, looping through the array `self.contacts`:

```
 // First check if friend, and remove/add to
            friendsURL.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

                for oneSnapshot in snapshot.children {

                    for oneContact in contactsArray {

                        for oneContactPhoneNum in oneContact.phoneNumbers {

                            let phoneNumber = oneContactPhoneNum.value as! CNPhoneNumber

                            contactNumber = phoneNumber.stringValue

                            // Clean the number
                            let stringArray = contactNumber!.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(
                                NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet)
                            let newString = "1" + stringArray.joinWithSeparator("")

                            let firebaseFriendNumber = oneSnapshot.value["phoneNumber"] as! String

                            if newString == firebaseFriendNumber {

                                self.friends.append(Friend(userName: oneSnapshot.value["userName"] as! String,phoneNumber: firebaseFriendNumber, status: 2, name: oneContact.givenName, userID: oneSnapshot.key))

                                // Remove that contact
                                self.contacts.removeObject(oneContact)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Now do the users search:
                for oneContact in self.contacts {
                    for oneContactNumer in oneContact.phoneNumbers {

                        let phoneNumber = oneContactNumer.value as! CNPhoneNumber

                        contactNumber = phoneNumber.stringValue

                        let stringArray = contactNumber!.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(
                            NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet)
                        let newString = "1" + stringArray.joinWithSeparator("")

                        let usersURL: Firebase! = Firebase(url: firebaseMainURL + "presentUserIDUserNameByPhoneNumber/" + newString)

                        // Check db:

                        usersURL.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

                            if snapshot.childrenCount > 1 {

                                // They are users (but not your friends):
                                self.friends.append(Friend(userName: snapshot.value["userName"] as! String, phoneNumber: snapshot.key, status: 1, name: "test", userID: snapshot.value["userID"] as! String))

                                let userName = snapshot.value["userName"] as! String

                                print("Friends name: " + userName)

                                // Remove that contact
                                self.contacts.removeObject(oneContact)

                            }

                        })

                    }

                }

            })
```

How can I test and check when the second, on `usersURL`, has completed before allowing other actions to occur in app?

Comment: The usersURL observe has 'completed' once the code in the block starts executing. i.e. when that 'if snapshot.children' fires, that means all of the data has been retrieve from Firebase. So do whatever you need to do inside that block and then have the last line call the next thing that should happen - show a window or update a tableView etc. Is there a reason why you can't use that block as your 'test'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach to signal completion of an asynchronous function is using a completion handler. You already used completion handlers in the Firebase API and there are many APIs in the system frameworks, so I don't explain that further.

Given this approach, wrap your code into a function, say `updateContacts`  with a completion handler. Usually an asynchronous function returns the computed *value* or an *error*. In some cases, it just succeeds or fails - without returning a value. You express this in the signature of the completion handler. Your function `updateContacts` may not compute a value, but it may fail or succeed anyway. Then, you can use an optional error: if it is `nil`, the task succeeded, otherwise it contains the error that occurred.

When your underlying task has been completed, call the completion handler with the result.

**Note:** You *must* ensure, that the completion handler will be *eventually called*!

```
func updateContacts(completion: (ErrorType?)-> ()) {
    friendsURL.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        ...
            ...
                ...
                    usersURL.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
                        ...
                        let error = // nil or an error
                        completion(error)
                       return
                     }
        completion(nil)
    }    
}
```

Now, when you have an array of asynchronous subtasks, that will be called in parallel and you want to signal completion of `updateContacts` when all subtasks have been completed - you can utilise dispatch groups:

```
let group = dispatch_group_create()
var error: ErrorType?
contactNumbers.forEach { number in
    dispatch_group_enter(group)
    queryAsync(number) { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            // handle error
        } else {
            ...
        }             
        dispatch_group_leave(group)
    }
}
dispatch_group_notify(group, queue) {
    // call the completion handler of your function `updateContacts`:
    completion(error)
}
```

Comment: Question: what if I set the entire `contactNumbers.forEach { number in` within a  `dispatch_group_enter(group)` and `dispatch_group_leave(group)`,  (that is what I was doing but it was not waiting to complete all actions)

Comment: @Sauron It would call `..._enter` then then starting `N` asynchronous functions, and then immediately calling `..._leave`. If you subsequently call `..._notify` with a closure, this closure will be called immediately (on the queue) because the group is empty. But the `N` asynchronous functions will still running.